Defects in Blender 4.1
Display Issues in Blender 4.1.1
Hello everyone,
Can you please help me understand why these defects appear on my model? The model is intact and undamaged. This issue is not only with this model but with all of them. When viewed from a different angle, the defect disappears and appears on another side. How can this be resolved, and what is causing it?
Thank you!



Hello it may be the Clip Start or End in the N panel > View

It looks as if you may have overlapping edges there. Try going into Edit mode, selecting All and hitting M > Merge by Distance. If that doesn't sort the problem we may need to see your Blend file.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

It's true. The problem was in ‘Clip Start or End’
Thank you very much!
@moonboots

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Tweak the Clip Start or End values in the N panel > View:

